# SQL Server - how to sum field from multiple table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables like this

[image: Sql]

I want to sum `SewingPrice` from `WorkDetail` table and `CombinationPrice` from `Details` table based on `WorkDate` in `WorkHeader` table. I'm using this query and it fails (returns 1700 for `CombinationPrice` and 80400 for `SewingPrice`). I want to return 1700 for `CombinationPrice` and 20400 for `SewingPrice`.

```
select 
    SUM(det.CombinationPrice) CombinationPrice, 
    SUM(wd.SewingPrice) SewingPrice 
from 
    Details det 
join 
    WorkDetail wd on det.WorkDetailId = wd.WorkDetailId 
join 
    WorkHeader wh on wd.WorkHeaderId = wh.WorkHeaderId  
where 
    wh.DateStart = '2013-12-20'
```

Comment: You will have to group your results by `wd.WorkHeaderID`

Comment: @Kiril No, It still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM WorkHeader WH
  INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(SewingPrice) SumSew, WorkHeaderID
          FROM WorkDetail
          GROUP BY WorkHeaderID) Sew ON
    WH.WorkHeaderID = Sew.WorkHeaderID
  INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(Det.CombinationPrice) SumCombo, WD.WorkHeaderID
          FROM Details Det
            INNER JOIN WorkDetail WD on WD.WorkDetailID = Det.WorkDetailID
          GROUP BY WorkHeaderID) Combo ON
    Combo.WorkHeaderID = WH.WorkHeaderID
  WHERE WH.WorkDate = '2013-12-20'
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, you have to use `group by`

```
select 
    wd.workHeaderID,
    SUM(det.CombinationPrice) CombinationPrice, 
    SUM(wd.SewingPrice) SewingPrice 
from 
    WorkHeader wh 
    left join 
    workdetail wd on wd.WorkHeaderId = wh.WorkHeaderId  
left join 
    (select det.workdetailid ,SUM(det.CombinationPrice)combinationprice from details det group by det.workdetailid)as det on det.WorkDetailId = wd.WorkDetailId 

where 
    wh.workdate = '20131220'

 group by wd.workheaderid
```